# Ubiquity Powerstation radio switch port not working

Tags: wifi, access-point

Is there a way i can still connect to my Ubiquity Powerstation 5 Radio that the ethernet switch port is not working with my Laptop.

When connected to the PoE, it powered up and the WAN light indicator comes up after some time but when connected to a Laptop the LAN will not connect?

Is there a way i could still access the radio to configure it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That AP only has a 10/100 Ethernet port on it. You will need a crossover cable to connect to it.